# How to retrieve all book categories from Amazon by ASIN?

Tags: amazon-product-api

Could anybody tell how to retrieve list of categories from a book by ASIN like [this website does](https://www.bklnk.com/categories.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Amazon Product Advertising API v5 for this. Create a *GetItems* request with the ASIN (e.g 1641521198) as *ItemsId* and request the BrowserNoteInfo.BrowserNodes and BrowserNoteInfo.BrowserNodes.Ancestor as *ressources*.

The response will look like the following:

```
{
 "ItemsResult": {
  "Items": [
   {
    "ASIN": "1641521198",
    "BrowseNodeInfo": {
     "BrowseNodes": [
      {
       "Ancestor": {
        "Ancestor": {
         "Ancestor": {
          "Ancestor": {
           "ContextFreeName": "Books",
           "DisplayName": "Books",
           "Id": "283155"
          },
          "ContextFreeName": "Subjects",
          "DisplayName": "Subjects",
          "Id": "1000"
         },
         "ContextFreeName": "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
         "DisplayName": "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
         "Id": "6"
        },
        "ContextFreeName": "Baking",
        "DisplayName": "Baking",
        "Id": "4196"
       },
       "ContextFreeName": "Bread Baking",
       "DisplayName": "Bread",
       "Id": "4197",
       "IsRoot": false
      },
      {
       "Ancestor": {
        "Ancestor": {
         "Ancestor": {
          "Ancestor": {
           "ContextFreeName": "Books",
           "DisplayName": "Books",
           "Id": "283155"
          },
          "ContextFreeName": "Subjects",
          "DisplayName": "Subjects",
          "Id": "1000"
         },
         "ContextFreeName": "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
         "DisplayName": "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
         "Id": "6"
        },
        "ContextFreeName": "Cooking by Ingredient",
        "DisplayName": "Cooking by Ingredient",
        "Id": "4208"
       },
       "ContextFreeName": "Natural Food Cooking",
       "DisplayName": "Natural Foods",
       "Id": "4340",
       "IsRoot": false
      },
      {
       "Ancestor": {
        "Ancestor": {
         "Ancestor": {
          "Ancestor": {
           "ContextFreeName": "Books",
           "DisplayName": "Books",
           "Id": "283155"
          },
          "ContextFreeName": "Subjects",
          "DisplayName": "Subjects",
          "Id": "1000"
         },
         "ContextFreeName": "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
         "DisplayName": "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
         "Id": "6"
        },
        "ContextFreeName": "Main Courses & Side Dishes",
        "DisplayName": "Main Courses & Side Dishes",
        "Id": "4234"
       },
       "ContextFreeName": "Garnishing Meals",
       "DisplayName": "Garnishes",
       "Id": "7696136011",
       "IsRoot": false
      }
     ]
    },
    "DetailPageURL": "https://www.amazon.com/dp/1641521198?tag=getabstractcom&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

With that data you should be able to determinate the categories such as
Books » Cookbooks, Food & Wine » Baking » Bread Baking 
or
Books » Cookbooks, Food & Wine » Main Courses & Side Dishes » Garnishing Meals

More information about the PAAPI5 you find [here](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/). There exists as well some SDK for different programming languages such as Java, PHP, Node or Python.